# Delay Entity Framework SaveChanges to the next action

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a form where the user can insert photos for an item with jquery.

I can't save the images at the moment the user upload them, because the item is not yet created causing a foreign key conflict.

I have created a base controller that both the itemcontroller and fileuploadcontroller inherit. In this basecontroller a new DBContext object is created.

I fill the images the user uploads in this shared DBContext and when the user finally submits the form the item is created and saved (in its own DBContext) and then I try to save the images with the shared DBContext.

The problem is that at that point, my previously added images are not in the DBContext anymore so images are not saved in the database.

What I'm doing wrong? I could delete the foreign key to solve the problem, but I don't think is good idea.

Comment: Without code this is very hard to judge. You must find a way to save the item and the images through one context. It all depends on how items and images are associated whether this is easy or not.

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid using multiple contexts per request (if possible), or at least just one at a time. I would definitely avoid creating shared DBContexts in base controller classes. In fact, I'd avoid using EF code in the presentation layer altogether.
I prefer to have a "business logic" layer or "service" layer (the latter is an overloaded term) that I then use to call a repository layer. But for the sake of simplicity, just having one layer works.
You can make a graph of related entities that are ***all*** new, and add them at once. EF will insert them all. Don't try to insert child entities that already exist using this process, though. It will always try to add entities that are attached to this graph.

For images uploaded that don't yet exist, I'd populate a new entity with the data uploaded and add that to a new instance of the context. I'd then call `SaveChanges()` on the context at that point.

New service class:

```
public class ItemService
{
    public ItemEntity AddItem(ItemEntity e)
    {
        if (e != null)
        {
            using (var context = new MyContext())
            {
                IDbSet<ItemEntity> entitySet = context.Set<ItemEntity>();
                var entity = entitySet.Add(e);
                context.SaveChanges();
                return entity;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Code that initializes a graph and adds the new entity with its related entities:

```
// gather the images into their respective entities, say Image1 and Image2 for an example
var Image1 = new ImageEntity { // set the properties here };
var Image2 = new ImageEntity { // set the properties here };
var newItem = new ItemEntity
              {
                  // set various scalar properties here
                  Images = {
                               Image1, Image2
                           }
              };
var service = new ImageService();
var addedEntity = service.AddItem(newItem); // adds and commits
```